# Make Facebook API call object public - object undefined at the moment

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, object

I am kind of new to jQuery/javascript and struggling to make the 'userData' object public available. The Facebook call works fine. Within the Facebook call the console logs the 'userData' object just how I want it. However, I don't know how to make the object publicly available, so I can re-use it. the console log at the moment reports that 'userData' is not defined. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!
Ron

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture', function(userProfile) {
  var userData = {  
    first_name  :   userProfile.first_name, 
    last_name   :   userProfile.last_name,
    userid      :   userProfile.id,
    picture     :   userProfile.picture 
 };             

 return userData;
});
console.log(userData);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's that `var` keyword in front of your userData which scopes it inside the callback function.  Asign it to a global variable and you can use it globally.  Not how I'd actually recommend building your system, but it's useful for debugging.

```
var globalUserData;

FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture', function(userProfile) {
    globalUserData = {  
      first_name  :   userProfile.first_name, 
      last_name   :   userProfile.last_name,
      userid      :   userProfile.id,
      picture     :   userProfile.picture 
    };

    console.log(globalUserData);
    // do more stuff with the user data here.
});
```

Also note that the `console.log` runs immediately after you *initiate* the FB API call, which will be long before it finishes and fires the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, I still don't get it to work. I see you point about the console.log. However, when I replace this for something like:
$("#showme").prepend(globalUserData.first_name); 
...I still don't see anything. How come??